# OpenLDAP API Search

Tags: c++, c, api, ldap, openldap

I'm attempting to do an LDAP search using the OpenLDAP API. I've already successfully connected and bound to the server. I've done the search with ldap_search_ext_s() and parsed the result with ldap_parse_result(). However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the actual results of the search. Unfortunately, the OpenLDAP C API has changed recently and many of the existing examples on the Internet do not use the current API.

I've already attempted to use ldap_first_attribute(), ldap_next_attribute(), and ldap_get_values() as shown on http://www-archive.mozilla.org/directory/csdk-docs/search.htm (Example 6-13). However, it appears that ldap_get_values() is now deprecated and that ldap_get_values_len() is the closest replacement. Instead of returning a char**, the new function returns a berval**. I've attempted to tweak this example code by creating a berval* with the value of barval**[i]. This results in a successful compile, but a core dump at ber_scanf().

Does anyone know how to get the results of an LDAP search with the OpenLDAP C API?

**UPDATE:**

In particular, I'm asking how to get the attributes requested from the search message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look at the OpenLDAP API source code and seeing how the berval value was used, I eventually stumbled upon how to get it's value.

First, you have to get the first entry with `ldap_first_entry()`. Then, you need to get the first attribute in that entry with `ldap_first_attribute()`. Then, put the values in a berval** array with `ldap_get_values_len()`. The returned attribute values can then be access with `berval[i]->bv_val`.

You can get the next entries and attributes with `ldap_next_entry()` and `ldap_next_attribute()`, respectively.

I hope this helps anyone who has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a search request always contains a series of `SearchResultEntry` or `SeachResultReference` messages, this series terminated by a `SearchResultDone` message. Calling `getNextAttribute` (in any language and in any API) makes no sense whatever because the search results are a list of messages. An API should package the array of entries or references in such a way wherein the caller can simply retrieve the list of entries or references. Look for a method that does that.

Comment: How do I get the attributes requested from the message?

Answer (score 0):

hope the bellow function may help you,

```
int ldap_search_result(LDAP *ld, char *search_filter, char *search_base)
{
    LDAPMessage *result;
    BerElement *ber;
    char *attr;
    char **val;

    if(ldap_search_ext_s(ld, search_base, LDAP_SCOPE_CHILDREN, 
            search_filter, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, -1, &result) != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
        return -1;
    }

    if(ldap_count_entries(ld,result) != 1) {    // assuming search_filter is unique, 
                                                // matches only one entry, and so
                                                // search routine returns only one entry
        return -1;
    }

    if((attr = ldap_first_attribute(ldp, result, &ber)) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    do {
        if((val = ldap_get_values(ldp,result,attr)) == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        printf(" %s : %s \n", attr, val[0]); // assuming all attributes are single -
                                             //valued.
        ldap_memfree(attr);
        ldap_value_free(val);
    while((attr = ldap_next_attribute(ld,result,ber)) != NULL);
    return 0;
}
```